# mux.go:12: can't find import: "github.com/gorilla/context"`

Tags: go

I'm trying to install my Go test package, but I keep getting this error:

`D:\Developpement\golang\src\github.com\gorilla\mux\mux.go:12: can't find import: "github.com/gorilla/context"`

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/pat"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
  mux := pat.New()
  mux.Get("/user/:name/profile", http.HandlerFunc(profile))

  http.Handle("/", mux)

  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func profile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  params := r.URL.Query()
  name := params.Get(":name")
  w.Write([]byte("Hello " + name))
}
```

My `GOROOT` is pointing to Go's installation root, and `GOPATH` to my workspace root.

**EDIT**

Here's the output of `go env`:

```
D:\Développement\golang\src\github.com\jpmonette\hello>go env
set GOARCH=386
set GOBIN=
set GOCHAR=8
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=386
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=D:\Développement\golang\
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-g -O2 -m32 -mthreads
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

Comment: Did you install pat with `go get github.com/gorilla/pat` or did you install pat manually?

Comment: Your code resides in `D:\Developpement\golang` but your GOPATH points to `D:\Développement\golang` which is not the same: e and é. Don't be cute with paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed your directory name D:\Développement\golang\src\github.com\jpmonette\hello has non ascii character. I am not sure if Go handles these properly.

Alex

Comment: I recommend as a best practice to only use ascii characters (without whitepsace, ...) for directory and file names.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks @alex

Comment: I think this https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3754 is all that is needed to fix your issue. I could be wrong.